# Recreating a method invocation (using reflection)

Tags: java, reflection

How do I recreate a method invocation? when all I've got is the list of methods, obtained by `getDeclaredMethods()`, and converted into a `HashMap<String,Method>` and a list of its parameters' Classes, obtained by `getParameterTypes()`.

Suppose I get  a string from the user and I want to invoke it:

```
"print(3,"Hello World!",true,2.4f)"
```

And the method `print(int,String,boolean,float)` is part of the getMethods() array. I'm having trouble to figure out how do I compose the invocation. So far this is what I got:

```
private static final Pattern functionCall = Pattern.compile(String.format("^%s\\(%s?\\)$", "(\\w+)", "(.*)"));

if( (m = functionCall.matcher(line)).find() ) {
    String function = m.group(1); // in this example = "print"
    String arguments = m.group(2); // in this example = "3,\\"Hello World!\\",true,2.4f"
    if( methods.containsKey(function) ) {
        Method method = methods.get(function);
        Class<?>[] paramsExpected = method.getParameterTypes();
        String [] paramsActual = arguments.split(",");
        if( paramsExpected.length != paramsActual.length ) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(function + ": bad number of arguments");
        }
        for( Class<?> param: paramsExpected) {
            ???????
        }
        method.invoke(context, ??????);
```

To be perfectly clear, I don't know in advance what string the user will input, I have to check it against the available methods and their parameters, and if I find it, then I have to invoke it with the parameters supplied by the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This what you need to do.  One option is to use the [ConverterUtils.convert](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils//api/index.html?org/apache/commons/beanutils/Converter.html) method of BeanUtils to convert string to object of specific type. This will work for built in types.

```
    Object[] args = new Object[paramsExpected.length];
    int i = 0;  
    for( Class<?> param: paramsExpected) {
        args[i] = convertStringToType(paramsActual[i], param);
        i  = i +1;
    }
    method.invoke(context, args);

    Object convertStringToType(String input, Class<?> type) {
      return ConverterUtils.convert(input,type);
    }
```

Comment: This is definitely one step forward. I took a look at the link you supplied and it is not clear how does it deal with primitives like int, boolean, etc. It seems it only converts Objects. `convert(Class type, Object value) Convert the specified input object into an output object of the specified type.` (And of course you forgot to increment `i`, but that's minor)

Comment: The reflection api doesn't distinguish between primitive and object wrappers.  Even primitives get converted to their equivalent wrapper types. You can verify that by printing the class name of each parameter.

Comment: I think I will take your answer partially an convert the parameter by myself, using `param.getSimpleName()` or `param.getCanonicalName()` and then apply the appropiate `valueOf()`